# Why does Chrome Audits show no errors on local development, but when deployed shows 3 errors

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've been debugging my PWA app for days now. When checking my app, locally, inside Chrome Audits, all passed (of course, except 'uses HTTPS' because it is still being served on localhost) and showed no errors. The fallback.html (which serves as an offline html) shows up on localhost whenever an un-cached file is being served. However, when I deployed it to firebase, I went to my pwa app url address and tested it again inside Chrome Audits, then it showed 3 errors. The app wouldn't response with offline. There is no problem with the caching. Everything is cached. Even the update for cache versions works. Only the offline html doesn't fire up whenever an un-cached file is being served (no internet connection).

- This is the screenshot on localhost
  [image]
- This is the screenshot after deployed using https url
  [image]

  1. I have already checked App Shell assets (inside /sw.js) if there are any cached items that don't exist.
  2. Tested on mobile devices, turned off all wifi connectivity.
  3. Checked all relative urls.
  4. Tried changing start_url to `'/index.html'`, `'/?utm_source=a2hs'`, `'/'` => nothing worked.

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "short_name": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "start_url": "/?utm_source=a2hs",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "background_color": "#e1f1d6",
  "theme_color": "#caeab7",
  "orientation": "portrait-primary",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/img/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "72x72"
    },
    {
      "src": "/img/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "96x96"
    },
    {
      "src": "/img/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "128x128"
    },
    {
      "src": "/img/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "144x144"
    },
    {
      "src": "/img/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "152x152"
    },
    {
      "src": "/img/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "/img/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "384x384"
    },
    {
      "src": "/img/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Make sure you TOTALLY clear out your browser's cache and uninstall service worker from previous visits/tests to your HTTPS site. Check for console errors. Also, look at the service worker in the dev tools to make sure it shows no errors.

Comment: Thanks. But, I already checked the 'Application' tab and always make sure that it has always the latest by clearing the data, unregistering the worker. I also cache versioning. Everytime I deploy I always change the cache version.

Comment: After changing the cache version did you remove all the previous cached versions. Its a must as the service worker takes files from those previous caches too sometimes.```js
caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
  cacheNames.forEach(function(cacheName) {
    caches.delete(cacheName);
  });
});
```